# Merge two streams coming from firebase firestore Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, stream

I want two streams to be combined as one result and then return it from my function. I have two streams coming from firebase. So I have to merge data1 into data2, something like concatenation of both the streams and then return. What i have acheived so for is:

```
Future<Stream<QuerySnapshot>> getMsgs(userId, toId) async {

    var data1 = await _fireStore
    .collection(_collection)
    .where('messageFrom', isEqualTo: userId).where('messageTo', isEqualTo: toId)
    .orderBy('createdOn', descending: true)
    .snapshots();

    var data2 = await _fireStore
    .collection(_collection)
    .where('messageFrom', isEqualTo: toId).where('messageTo', isEqualTo: userId)
    .orderBy('createdOn', descending: true)
    .snapshots();

    // I have tried this, but this will be the list
    return [data1, data2];
    
    // I have tried this, but didn't worked
    return StreamZip([data1, data2]);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: see [CombineLatestStream](https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/CombineLatestStream-class.html)

Comment: @pskink Can you just please elaborate how to use that?

Comment: you need to use it instead of `StreamZip` which was wrong

Comment: What kind of values are you trying to concatenate? pskink's response works if it's numerical or you require a result for each combination of results (and yes it would be as simple as replacing `StreamZip([data1, data2])` with `CombineLatestStream([data1, data2])` if either of those is the case; the link they provided explains how to use it), but if you want something else that it would be best if you explained what the data you're trying to concatenate is.